# Ambiguous Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and DataTable

Tags: vb.net

I work with `VS 2013` ans Microsoft Office 2010. I import into my Form these two references:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

I have this line of code:

```
Public Dt As New DataTable
```

I have not any problem with `Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, but with `Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.
When I build project I will have this error message:

> 'DataTable' is Ambigious,imported from the namespaces or types
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word,System.Data

The error is underlined by a blue line under the word (DataTable)

Comment: Do the same thing you did with the Excel interop namespace, then: `Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, or `Imports DataTable = System.Data.DataTable`. Which fits best.

Comment: Thank you very much Jimi.The problem is solved with this (Imports DataTable = System.Data.DataTable).Thank you very much